# FishPig WordPress Magento Integration get Category posts on page

Tags: wordpress, magento, fishpig

I am using the FishPig extension to integrate WordPress to Magento website. All is working fine, except that I cannot make the WordPress plugins to work.

Is this possible to run WordPress plugins in Magento through the above mentioned extension?

If not how can I show the posts of specific category on the page with all the options of WordPress like excerpt etc?

Comment: wordpress extension won't work in magento. It should work in wordpress site only.

Comment: That isn't entirely accurate.  It is possible to run Wordpress extensions in Wordpress & Magento using the FishPig integration.  It is a fully installed Wordpress version so I'm not sure why you would think you couldn't run extensions in it.

Comment: Which Wordpress extension are you trying to run and what is the result?

Comment: In Fishpig they have provided support for only few plugins. You need to hire a developer or visit this http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/add-ons/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When integrated into Magento, the WordPress code is not loaded. Instead, data is retrieved directly from the WordPress database and displayed via Magento models, blocks, controllers etc. This means that any plugin installed in WordPress that usually runs on the front end of your blog will be not loaded when displaying the blog on the frontend, which means that any shortcodes or widgets offered by this plugin will not work.

To get these plugins to work, an extra Magento extension is required to add support for it. As there are thousands of WordPress plugins, it is not possible for me to add support for all of them. I have therefore tried to add support to the more popular plugins as part of the free extension and the more difficult plugins, via [add-on Magento WordPress extensions](http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/add-ons/).

That being said, the Category Posts plugin for WordPress is supported by the extension and should work without any add-on extensions.

I recommend upgrading Magento WordPress Integration to the latest version, ensuring that you have the Twenty Twelve theme installed and you are using the correct [Category Posts plugin for WordPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/category-posts/).